# how to get records from sqlite database with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

I'm trying to get list of records from sqlite database and return it.
I know that since node.js is Async, I have to use callback to pass those objects, but whenever I run the callback I still get an empty array:

```
const Query= (category)=>{
        return new Promise ((resolve, reject)=> {
            let db= connectDB();
            let sql=`
                SELECT * 
                FROM Events JOIN Categories ON Events.categoryID==Categories.categoryID
                WHERE Categories.category== ?`;
            db.each(sql,[category],(err,row)=>{
                err ? reject(err) : 
                    resolve(row);
            });
            closeDB(db);
        });
};

const getByCategory=(category)=>{
    let output=[];
    let promise=Query(category);
    promise.then((res)=>output.push(res)).catch((err)=>console.log(err));
    return output;
}

const res= getByCategory('assualt');
console.log(res);
```

When I try to print the rows it is done successfully.

**How can I get data with `db.each()` and return it?**

Comment: Update: with the promise approach I succeeded to return the rows. the problem was that I didn't use the 'complete' argument that the method 'each()' needs. The sig of this method is: 
```
each(query:string, [params], result:callback, comlete:callback)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a example for db.each:

```
db.each("SELECT * FROM Dog WHERE breed = '
```

Labrador'",
(error, row) => {
/*gets called for every row our query returns*/
console.log(`${row.name} is a good dog`);
});

Check if category has a valid content. Evtl. it is better to put the query in the first step direct into the Code (no const) so that you can debug it.

Comment: When I try to print the results it works fine. The problem is when I try try to return the results.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using callback try using [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). Instead of this

```
err ? reject(err) : 
                callback(row);
```

Do this

```
err ? reject(err) : 
                resolve(row);
```

and your result would be in then of promise i.e

```
getByCategory('assualt',getResults).then(res=>{
    console.log(res);//Your result
})
```

Because of the asynchronous nature of nodejs, whenever nodejs want to access any outer resource(SQLite in this case) it does not wait for the result instead it attach a listener(callback) which are being replaced by promises now to it and executes further code that's why you are not getting the required result. Try learning about how [nodejs works asynchronously](https://blog.risingstack.com/node-hero-async-programming-in-node-js/#:%7E:text=asynchronous%20programming%20model.-,Asynchronous%20programming%20in%20Node.,file%20reading%20process%20in%20Node.).

Comment: So I tried your approach, but I still get an empty array whenever I try to return the results array. what am I missing?
I updated the code in the question.

Comment: @orkandabi This is not what I said, you should wait for the promise to resolve, getByCategory itself contains async code, your result would be in ".then" always. First, try to learn how nodejs works asynchronously then you will get your answer.